# How do I do that "change of view" sliding effect?

Tags: android, mobile, frontend

Several apps (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram) make use of a "touch enabled" effect where the user drags the entire screen and it changes the view and the menu option. Do not confuse with the slide effect of the menu.

I would like to develop an app with this effect, but I can not find any source on this subject, as I do not even know the NAME of this component or effect.

Just to illustrate: in Whatsapp it changes the CHATS, STATUS and CALLS options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking is a viewpager with a tabLayout.

Take a look at this tutorial for implementation

https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Awesome, please if the answer helped consider marking the answer as accepted by pressing the green tick in the answer